# how to get response to index js from service worker if page goes offline

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am using a service of city list, in my main page using HTTP request I had fetched the list and showing in autocomplete, so I want to know by using service worker how to store that city list in cache and use in offline mode

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker):

First you have install a service worker. Next you have tell what kind of requests needs to be intercepted and how you would like to respond to a request. (Caching Strategy).

in your index.html add

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
  .then(function(registration) {
    console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', error);
  });
}
```

and then in your service-worker.js add

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open('cache-name').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
          cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
          return response;
        });
      });
    })
  );
});
```

This will cache all your network GET requests. So from your next request it'll check the cache first and only if the data is not there it'll make a network fetch.

Comment: I am using post request how to handle that situation

Comment: Post request can't be cached using service worker directly. There may be workarounds for this. Check [this](https://medium.com/web-on-the-edge/offline-posts-with-progressive-web-apps-fc2dc4ad895).

Comment: self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
   fetch(event.request.clone()).catch(function() {
 // If it doesn't work, post a failure message to the client
 self.clients.match(thisClient).then(function(client) { // giving error over here saying thisclient is not defined
         client.postMessage({
         message: "Post unsuccessful.",
   alert: alert // A string we instantiated earlier
         });
 });
 // Respond with the page that the request originated from
 return caches.match(event.request.clone().referrer);
    })

  );
});